# How do i track a file size using FileSystemWatcher until the file size not change any more?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The watcher method:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = null;
        private void watch()
        {
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = SavePathTextBox.Text;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = "*.JPG";
            watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
```

Then in the event Changed i'm watching if the file is busy or not and also watching the file size:

```
void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFileReady(e.FullPath) == false)
        {
            this.Invoke((Action)delegate { label6.Text = "Busy"; });
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
            {
                var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
                var theSize = info.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Invoke((Action)delegate { label6.Text = "File Ready"; });
                watcher.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

I saw with a breakpoint that it's getting to the part:

```
var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
var theSize = info.Length;
```

But it's never get to the else part:

```
this.Invoke((Action)delegate { label6.Text = "File Ready"; });
watcher.Dispose();
```

How do i know when the file size never change any more ? Maybe the whole code in the Changed event is wrong but i want to check if the file is busy or not and also to track the file size until the size stop changing.

Comment: Write the result to a temproary file and move it to another location when finished...

Answer (score 1):

The FileSystemWatcher Changed event is only raised when changes are made to file or directory being monitored.  The event is NOT fired if there were No Changes.  See [The MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

According to [This MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6xf43e0(v=vs.110).aspx), the WatcherChangeTypes Enumeration does not even have any options for "No Change"

If you're waiting for another process to finish writing to a file then I suggest implementing a timer that will check if the file has changed since the last timer tick.  Of course your timer timespan should be long enough to capture the slowest change time that could happen.  If you're waiting for a user to, then you could be waiting a long time.

Alternatively you could watch for open file handles to your target file.
See the [MS File Handle utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) for example.
Perhaps call that utility on your timer tick with the command line arguments set for your target file, then when it does not return any open handles, you will know other processes have closed their handles.  That doesn't mean they will not re-open the file though.